# How long should you wait to accept an answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I've asked a couple questions here and I was just wondering what kind of time frame should I be looking at before accepting an answer? Since this is a beta site I'm inclined to leave it open longer to maybe get some more traffic.

Comment: http://meta.homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/152/should-there-be-a-forced-delay-before-getting-an-accepted-answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I definitely wouldn't accept too early -- that's the most common mistake we see, and it does tend to inhibit any additional answers from arriving.

In fact, we have prevention mechanisms to deny "too early" accepts for 15 minutes after the question is asked.

I'd say wait at least a few days, perhaps longer if you have a "long tail" sort of question that may take weeks or months for the right people to find it in a web search, and answer..

Comment: Of course, if it's a simple direct question (what temperature is boiling at my elevation), then a simple answer could be accepted quickly.

Comment: @pj I'd still wait a day as a courtesy to anyone else interested in answering .. that's a rule of thumb

Comment: More like a rule of wrist... i kid. sounds good!